# Salesforce Integration Rest

Tags: integration, rest

I have a requirement where i have to fetch response from Call Back Url in salesforce. I am not sure how to create a Call Back Url and how to execute a class to parse the XML response. 
Basically I am integrating Right Signature with Salesforce. I need to update my record when Right Sign sends a response(XML) to the Call Back Url
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hello! Welcome to Salesforce StackExchange. Please edit your question to add more detail. What are you trying to do, what have you tried so far, why didn't it work, and what do you think is wrong. In other words, show us the code you've tried so far, and be clear about why it isn't working.

Comment: Thanks @ChristianCarter for your response. Please let me know if you need more detail.

Comment: Please show the code you have tried so far and what isn't working. Have you created a Force.com Site or an Apex REST endpoint for your callback URL?

Comment: I have not created any Force.com Site. I Guess a Apex Rest Endpoint will work but I dont know how to implement it.
Status Callbacks
Each time a document is signed, RS will POST an xml update to the specified callback location containing the <status> and <guid>.

Example Callback POST:
<callback>
               <callback-type>Document</callback-type>
               <guid>dl3jsdf9850dfkl3-dfl2</guid>
               <status>signed</status>
               <created-at>2014-11-05 16:36:08 -0800</created-at>
               <signed-at>2014-11-05 16:46:08 -0800</signed-at>
         </callback>

Comment: Above is the format of the XML response I will get from the external server. I have to specify a Call Back URL so that the system can send me a response and then I will parse that response using Apex Class.

Comment: So yes, you need to create some sort of place for that service to call back to. You can accomplish this with Force.com sites and an Apex REST endpoint that the force.com site can access. You're going to want to learn about both of those technologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a public Force.com Site, and then give that Site Guest User Profile access to an Apex REST class to create a public Apex REST endpoint. That's the high level of how you'd do this, you can find details on that process [over at developerforce](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2012/02/quick-tip-public-restful-web-services-on-force-com-sites.html).

Then, you'll want to study the Apex Developer's Guide to see how Apex REST can be implemented to accept POST calls, and you'll want to read the reference on XML parsing. It should be fairly straight forward once you have all the pieces.

Comment: Can this be done creating Connected Apps?

Comment: It allows me to create a Call back URL and I guess passing the Oauth Parameters in call back url this can be done.

Comment: A Connected App is a way of allowing an off-platform app that you create to access your Salesforce instance. In a Connected App, the "callback url" is the url on the off-platform service to call back to, not a callback url on the platform

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will try to implement this using Force.com site and Rest.